# Integrate twitter API with javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to use twitter api to sign up users for my web site using twitter .
i used this code that provide in api

```
<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  t = window.twttr || {};
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
 js = d.createElement(s);
 js.id = id;
 js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

 t._e = [];
 t.ready = function(f) {
  t._e.push(f);
};

return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>
```

But now i want to get user details that logged into twitter
how can i do that???

Comment: See the twitter documentation: You need to have OAuth flow first. https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in

Comment: @AntonNovopashin thanks .this is first time i'm trying to use this api so do you know any site with a example tutorial because that documentation is not clear ,

Comment: Twitter has a lot of information. https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/single-user